# Using Coojah + Blader (but any download manager any) to resume the download

Tags: download, download-manager

I have to keep switching download managers. First, I was using VLC media player to download mms, and then I started using [Coojah](http://www.hensence.com/en/coojah/) (with Blader) to download an RTMP stream, and then I don't know what I will use next.

One common problem faced by all: The stream temporarily goes off for a few seconds/minutes, and the download manager doesn't resume! It's a problem, because it's a live stream, so I end up losing content!

If you know a particular hack to Coojah and Blader that will allow me to reconnect, then cool... Otherwise, share some way to resume the download generally - like maybe keeping track of the file size using some software?

Please don't suggest alternate software to Coojah and Blader unless you know for sure it captures all RTMP streams and is free.